# Interesting behavior in my US Number formatting code

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to make 10 digits look like a US telephone number (i.e.(###) ###-####). My code does accomplish this first goal, but it also does something I can't quite figure out. When typing in the digits, the characters "()" show up before typing any other digits. I want the open parenthesis to appear first and the closing parathesis to appear after entering the third digit. Please don't give me a new solution; try to pin point the issue I'm describing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.drumbi-caller-number').live('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) {
    } else {
        inputval = $(this).val();
        var string = inputval.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
        var first3 = string.substring(0,3);
        var next3 = string.substring(3,6);
        var next4 = string.substring(6,9);  
        var string = ("(" + first3 + ")" + next3 + "-" + next4);
        $(this).val(string);
    }
});
</script>
```

Here's a jsFiddle that displays this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/bigthyme/j6kHn/3/

Comment: Note that `$(this).val();` can be simply `this.value`.

Comment: It is happening just because you are not checking any length and the else is running for every keydown.

Comment: Please see my below answer, it should fit all your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the length of `first3` before appending the paren:

```
var string = ("(" + first3 + ((first3.length>=3)?")":"") + next3 + "-" + next4);
```

And although not in your question, you can do the same for the hyphen:

```
var string = ("(" + first3 + 
     // only append the ) if the you have 3+ chars
     ((first3.length>=3)?")":"") + 
     next3 + 
     // only append the - if the you have 6+ chars
     (((first3+next3).length>=6)?"-":"") + 
     next4);
```

You should also use `.on()` instead of `live()`;

See it all working in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6kHn/8/)

Comment: This solution works great! Not sure why that conditional didn't come to mind before. Cheers!

Comment: @bigthyme great to hear, would be appreciated if you marked it as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

replace `keydown` with `keyup`, on `keydown` the value of the input element isn't updated

also set your `string` conditionally, only if long enough:

```
var string = string.length > 2 ? ("(" + first3 + ")" + next3 + "-" + next4) : first3;
```

here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/j6kHn/10

btw: you should also replace `.live(...)` with `.on(...)` as `.live()` is deprecated..

Comment: Or better yet, use an onchange event for the actual text box instead of watching key presses.

Comment: You don't want an `on('change')` or it will only update when it loses focus

Comment: just reread the OP, missed the part that no parenthesis should be displayed for len < 3..

Answer (score 1):

Go with

```
$('.foo').on('keyup', function (event) {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3"));
});
```

Test this code **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/wMtfA/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code, it should fix all of your issues:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bN6Rh/3/

jQuery:

```
$('.foo').on('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == (8 || 37 || 39)) { }
    else {
        inputval = $(this).val();
        var string = inputval.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
        var first3 = string.substring(0, 3);
        var next3 = " " + string.substring(3, 6);
        var next4 = string.substring(6, 10);
        if (string.length < 3) { // Less than 3
            var string = "(" + first3;
        }
        else if (string.length > 2 && string.length < 7) { // More than 2 and less than 7
            var string = "(" + first3 + ")" + next3;
        }
        else { // Anything else
            var string = "(" + first3 + ")" + next3 + "-" + next4;
        }
        $(this).val(string);
    }
});​
```

The problem was that you weren't checking the number of characters so as soon as anything was entered it put in `()-`, the above code also adds the space you mentioned wanting.

The code could of course be more compressed:

```
$('.foo').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == (8 || 37 || 39));
    else {
        var str = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

        var f3 = str.substring(0, 3),
            n3 = " " + str.substring(3, 6),
            n4 = str.substring(6, 10);

        if (str.length<3) str = "(" + f3;
        else if (str.length>2&&str.length<7) str="("+f3+")"+n3;
        else str="("+f3+")"+n3+"-"+n4;

        this.value = str;
    }
});​
```

Comment: This is great! Though I believe @doublesharp's solution works better on mobile (esp. Android). Thanks for the help bud.

Comment: Actually our solutions are much alike, except that mine uses slightly less compact if statements and they're on the string length instead of the specific numbers length. The benefit of this becomes obvious if you only type 3 characters, my solution inserts `) ` while doublesharp's requires you to enter a fourth character and even then skips the space.